# What is the predictable behavior of changing SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF on the fly on a UDP socket?

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel, udp, setsockopt

What should be expected to happen if we resize the input buffer of a UDP server socket on the fly on a Linux system?

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, ...)
```

I am particularly interested in these questions:

- If I shrink below what is currently in the buffer, would this simply drop the oldest/newest? datagrams properly, or could it flush everything that's there, or worse could it corrupt data such as truncating a datagram?
- Would shrinking the buffer even save memory or something prevents that memory from being reused by the system?
- Is the behavior predictable or could it behave randomly at times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: the term "buffer" might be confusing: the kernel does not actually save packets in buffers of fixed size, but rather in queues called "backlogs" (see [`include/net/sock.h:400`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/net/sock.h#L400)). The size set through `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF` only limits the maximum size of the backlog.

> If I shrink below what is currently in the buffer, would this simply drop the oldest/newest?

No, what was already received is kept. No datagrams are thrown away. The only thing that happens when you do `setsockopt(SO_RECVBUF)` is that [the value of the `sk_rcvbuf` field of the socket is changed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/net/core/sock.c#L820). No other action is performed.

The real effect of this is only seen when receiving more packets: all subsequent datagrams that are received will be immediately dropped, and will continue being dropped until the queue shrinks under the set size (i.e. userspace receives enough datagrams).

> Would shrinking the buffer even save memory or something prevents that memory from being reused by the system?

As I said earlier, since the "buffer" is not really a buffer and does not have a fixed size, changing `SO_RECVBUF` will not change anything immediately.

There are two scenarios:

1. If the backlog size was *below* (or equal to) the specified size: the new maximum size will be limited, so it will save memory *in the future* at the cost of potentially losing packets.
2. If the backlog size was *above* the specified size: memory will eventually be freed when userspace receives the buffered packets, and it will not grow again over the set value. This will again save memory in the future.

> Is the behavior predictable or could it behave randomly at times?

Looking at the kernel code, I would say 100% predictable in the way I described above. However I am not entirely sure where this might be documented. I would say it's kind of intuitive if you think about send and receive "buffers" as queues (which they actually are).